# sidebar in 2020 theme as a widget

Tags: themes, widgets, sidebar

I am using the default 2020 theme for my wordpress site which has a static page displayed as the front-end.

Now I want a sidebar (right) to display my links (blogroll) and recent posts.

Where is the sidebar and how do I include it in as a widget in the 2020 theme ?
Or do I need to edit the singular.php file in include the sidebar div ?

Comment: By default, 2020 Theme comes with 2 sidebar placed in the footer. In the admin panel, appearance -> widgets, you may see 2 area named Footer 1, Footer 2, could drag widgets on the left hand side such as `Recent Posts`. However, if you want to place the sidebar to a specify layout location. I am afraid you might need to create your own template based on the 2020 Theme as an example.

Comment: Oh Ok, I was afraid I had to do that. I don't know why they removed the sidebar.php file. It was very appropriate.